# Graph search with O(log(N)(N+M)

Tags: search, graph, big-o

First an explanation: I'm implementing a package manager emulator in java, i.e. a package manager that just outputs the right things but doesn't actually install anything. The thing is I need to search through every package and all it's dependencies to see if they are all installed correctly. I've been told that it is possible to get worst-case running time equal to log(N)(N+M), where N is amount of packages and M is the amount of dependencies. I believe it is some kind of BFS implementation that needs to be done, maybe just do a BFS to each package and it's dependencies, so if I get to a package that has been checked through some other package's dependencies it will just skip over. This however, in my head, does not seem to have the right worst-case running time.

Does anyone have any idea on how to achieve getting the right running time?

Comment: What's wrong with `for each package { are all of its dependencies installed }` ?

Comment: That would work, however the running time would then be O(N*M), which is way to high. I need it to be O(log(N)(N+M)...

Comment: Why would it be O(NM)? M is the *total* number of dependencies, and in the trivial approach, you only examine each dependency once...

Comment: Fair enough, but still it would be N*(M(1) + M(2) + M(3)...M(N)), and wouldn't that in some cases be more than log(N)(N+M)?

Comment: No it would just be N + M(1) + M(2) + ... + M(N) = N + M

Comment: Wait..why is the N there then. Shouldn't it just be M(1) + M(2) + ... +M(N)? Also different packages could depend on the same package(s) so the M's wouldn't sum to M because there would be duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

I think that this can be done by a topological sort and is often done by piggybacking off of DFS, not BFS. That has a linear time of O(M + N).